# Galaxy S4G database: convert pixel to kpc

Tags: astronomy, computational-physics, units, galaxies, astrophotography

I am referring to S4G database (https://irsa.ipac.caltech.edu/data/SPITZER/S4G/overview.html ).
The information on the length of galaxies, and various length parameters are given in terms of pixels.

Is there a simple way to convert the pixel information to kpc?
I am just learning this field, so any information on how to go about converting pixel to kpc would be helpful.

Comment: Would [astronomy.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic Astronomy is one of the tags. Is that sufficient, or the question needs to be explicitly posted in astronomy.stackexchange ? I do see posts with astronomy tag appearing in astronomy.stackexchange.

Comment: From the [Pipeline readme page](https://irsa.ipac.caltech.edu/data/SPITZER/S4G/docs/pipelines_readme.html), it says that pixel scale is 0.75 arcsec/pixel. This means 1.333 parsec per pixel, if I'm understanding this correctly.

Comment: the definition of parsec says, if an object subtends an angle of 1 arcsec on the orbital diameter of earth, then it is at a distance of 1 parsec. So, I am not sure if 0.75 arcsec/pixel may mean 1.3333 parsec per pixel.

Comment: 0.75 arcsec/pixel is correct. However, in order to convert angular size to linear size (e.g. in kpc), you need to know the _distance_ to the galaxy in question. The conversion from angular size $a$ in arcsec to linear size $s$ in parsecs is then $s = a d/206265$.